# Problema con arreglos en Javascript, recorrer arreglo

Tags: javascript, array

Estuve intentando bastante, pero no encontré la forma de resolverlo, mi primer intento fue con un for in pero después de varios intentos intente por este.

La función recibe un array de objetos en donde se detalla nombre y tipo de dieta de los integrantes de un meeting. Debe retornar un objeto que diga cuantos menús de que tipo de dieta hay que pedir (a fines prácticos solo hay dieta "standard" y "vegan")

Por ej:

```
pedirComida([{nombre: "Harry", dieta: "standard"}, {nombre: "Luna", dieta: 'vegan'}, {nombre: "Goyle", dieta: "standard"}])
```

retorna {standard: 2, vegan: 1}

```
function pedirComida(array) {
    let reparto = {standard: 0, vegan: 0}

    if (array['standard'] === 'standard')
    {
       reparto.standard ++
    } 

    if(array['vegan'] === 'vegan')
    {
       reparto.vegan ++
    } 
     return reparto
}
```

Comment: De donde es este ejercicio ?? Creo haberlo visto unas 3 veces ya

Comment: `array` es un arreglo y no tiene las propiedades `standard` y `vegan`. Debes acceder a sus elementos mediante índices numéricos (0, 1, 2, 3, ...). Esos elementos tampoco tienen las propiedades `standard` y `vegan`. Si tienen la propiedad `dieta` que puede contener los valores  `"standard"` o `"dieta"`.

Answer (score 3):

##### Con [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function pedirComida(array){
 return array.reduce( (acc,item) => {
   if(item.dieta=="standard"){
     acc.standard++;
   }
   else{
     acc.vegan++;
   }
   return acc;
 },{standard:0, vegan: 0 });
}

//Comprobación
let res=pedirComida([{nombre: "Harry", dieta: "standard"}, {nombre: "Luna", dieta: 'vegan'}, {nombre: "Goyle", dieta: "standard"}]);

console.log(res);
```

#### Con for

```js
function pedirComida(array){
 let acc = {standard:0, vegan: 0 };
 
 for(let item of array){
   if(item.dieta=="standard"){
     acc.standard++;
   }
   else{
     acc.vegan++;
   }
 }
 return acc;
}

//Comprobación
let res=pedirComida([{nombre: "Harry", dieta: "standard"}, {nombre: "Luna", dieta: 'vegan'}, {nombre: "Goyle", dieta: "standard"}]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

Creo que la mejor manera es utilizando un `reduce` como te dice @Yussef. Pero creo que lo puedes optimizar un poco más. De esta manera te seguirá funcionando si hay otros tipos de dieta.

```js
const integrantesMeeting1 = [
  { nombre: 'Harry', dieta: 'standard' },
  { nombre: 'Luna', dieta: 'vegan' },
  { nombre: 'Goyle', dieta: 'standard' },
];

const integrantesMeeting2 = [
  { nombre: 'Harry', dieta: 'standard' },
  { nombre: 'Luna', dieta: 'vegan' },
  { nombre: 'Goyle', dieta: 'standard' },
  { nombre: 'Jonh', dieta: 'meat' },
  { nombre: 'Joe', dieta: 'fish' },
  { nombre: 'Josua', dieta: 'meat' },
];

const pedirComida = (dietas) => dietas.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
  ...acc,
  [cur.dieta]: (acc[cur.dieta] || 0) + 1,
}), {});

console.log(pedirComida(integrantesMeeting1));
console.log(pedirComida(integrantesMeeting2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Con Foreach, recorriendo la array de objetos y comprobando cada clave que contenga dieta:

```js
function pedirComida(array) {
    
    let reparto = {standard: 0, vegan: 0}

array.forEach(element => {
    if (element === 'standard') {
        reparto.standard += 1
    } else if (element === 'vegan') {
        reparto.vegan += 1
    }

    alert(JSON.stringify(element))

if (element.dieta === 'standard')
{
   reparto.standard ++
} 

if(element.dieta === 'vegan')
{
   reparto.vegan ++
} 
    
});

return reparto
   
} 

alert(JSON.stringify(pedirComida([{nombre: "Harry", dieta: "standard"}, {nombre: "Luna", dieta: 'vegan'}, {nombre: "Goyle", dieta: "standard"}])))
```